# How addressing works in assembly x86 Real Mode? Why does label return different values?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader, real-mode

I have two variants of code for bootloader (it should move 1kb stack after 512b of a bootloader code).
Start physical address is always 0x7c00 (label "start"). BIOS copies a bootloader code in RAM.
When I use "MOV SP, start+1024+512":

1. **SP** will be 0x7c00 + 1024 + 512, because physical address should be **SS:SP** = 0<<4 + 0x7c00 + 1024 + 512. So "start" = 0x7c00
2. **SP** will be 0 + 1024 + 512, because physical address should be **SS:SP** = 0x07c0<<4 + 1024 + 512. So "start" = 0x0000

But if I write "jmp start" proccessor will always go to the address 0x7c00. It will calculate

1. 0 + 0x07c0
2. 0x07c0<<4 + 0

Why does 'start' return different values in **MOV** and **LMP**? Or it will be the same, but in **MOV** proccessor doesn't add segment, and in **JMP** adds? Also is it true that in this case "start" will be calculated based on DS:SI and not CS:IP?
Another example. If I add code in the end

```
mov SI, main
lodsb ;write data from main to AL
```

Proccessor will always go to the full physical address segment+offset and get value 'S' in register **AL**. **SI** will be equal to offset only? And processor will add segment during execution of lodsb?

Extra questions:

How does processor execute "jmp main"? This instruction is above "mov ds, ax". Therefore code in the 2 variant has an error, but it works.

What is the value of **CS** register by default when BIOS loads bootloader? Obviously CS:IP should be 0x7c00.

1 variant

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x7c00]
start:  ;offset= 0x7c00
jmp main
db    "Some data" ;actually fake BIOS Parameter Block(BPB)
main: 
mov ax, 0 
mov ds, ax ; data segment =0.
mov ss, ax ; stack segment = 0
mov sp, start+1024+512 ;stack pointer = 0x7c00+1024+512
```

2 variant

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x0000]
start:  ;offset= 0x0000
jmp main
db    "Some data" ;actually fake BIOS Parameter Block(BPB) 
main:
mov ax, 0x07c0 
mov ds, ax ; data segment =0x07c0.
mov ss, ax ; stack segment =0x07c0.
mov sp, start+1024+512 ;stack pointer = 0+1024+512
```

Comment: Can you focus this a bit more?  There seem to be at least 10 questions here, which is about 9 too many, and I'm not sure how to even begin answering without writing an entire book on 8086 memory architecture.

Comment: But maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/43397557/634919 is helpful.  Some BIOSes will set CS:IP to `0000:7c00`, others to `07c0:0000`.  What happens with the label `start` is independent of that, and determined by what value you choose for `org` in your source code.  You really need to keep segments and offsets separate in your mind, since that's what the CPU does; it only converts them to physical addresses at the very last stage.

Comment: And `jmp main` is likely to be a relative or "short" jump.  The assembler computes the number of bytes between the `jmp main` instruction itself and the label `main`, and encodes the difference into the address.  When executed, the CPU adds this value to the program counter IP, and leaves CS alone.  So it works correctly no matter how the segment registers are set, and no matter where the code happens to be loaded in memory.

Comment: Thank you @NateEldredge You answered on all my questions=) Additional thanks for jmp. I forgot this mechanism.

Comment: Correction: it's the number of bytes between the *next* instruction after the `jmp main`, and the label `main`.  And this is the case for both short and near direct jumps, just the question whether the difference fits in an 8-bit sign extended immediate, or 16 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... always go to the address 0x7c00. It will calculate ...

In segmented memory models, you should not only think about the effective (physical) address, but you always have to think of an address as a (16+16)-bit value in real mode or 16-bit protected mode or a (16+32)-bit value in 32-bit protected mode.

Let's say your program contains the instruction `mov al, cs:[100h]`.

This instruction will read some byte from the address `CS:0x100` which is effectively `(CS<<4)+0x100`.

If you perform a jump to `0x7C0:0`, this instruction will access the memory at address `(0x7C0<<4)+0x100=0x7D00`; if you perform a jump to `0:0x7C00`, this instruction will access the memory at address `(0<<4)+0x100=0x100`.

This means that your program does something different if you jump to `0x7C0:0` or to `0:0x7C00`. For this reason, it is said that `0x7C0:0` and `0:0x7C00` are two different addresses.

Let's assume that `main` is located at the physical address `0x7C40`.

This means that the address of `main` is neither `0x7C40` nor `0x40`, but it is either `0:0x7C40` (in "variant 1") or it is `0x7C0:0x40` (in "variant 2") because you always have to specify the address as pair of segment and offset.

In segmented memory models in protected mode this is even more complicated and it is much more important to use the correct segments!

> SI will be equal to offset only?
> Also is it true that in this case "start" will be calculated based on DS:SI and not CS:IP?

The `lodsb` instruction accesses address `DS:SI`, `stosb` accesses `ES:DI`.

This means that `SI` only holds the offset and `DS` only holds the segment.

The variants 1 and 2 will load different values to the `SI` register because `main` is located at address `0:0x7C40` (this means: `SI=0x7C40`) in one variant and at `0x7C0:0x40` (`SI=0x40`) in the other variant.

So in variariant 1, you'll have to set `DS=0`, in variant 2 you'll, have to set `DS=0x7C0`.

In one case, `lodsb` will access address `0:0x7C40`, in the other case, `lodsb` will access address `0x7C0:0x40`. In both cases the same byte in RAM is accessed: Physical address `0x7C40`.

> How does processor execute "jmp main"? This instruction is above "mov ds, ax". Therefore code in the 2 variant has an error, but it works.

There are two variants of the `JMP` instruction:

One variant does not write a fixed value to the `IP` register, but it adds some constant value to the `IP` register. So if `0x40` is added to `0x7C0:0`, code execution continues at `0x7C0:0x40`. And if `0x40` is added to `0:0x7C00`, code execution continues at `0:0x7C40`. In both cases, the next instruction is located at the physical address `0x7C40`. (Probably, the `jmp main` is this variant.)

The other variant takes a pair of segment and offset as an argument. You cannot jump to address `0x7C40`, but you can either jump to address `0:0x7C40` or to address `0x7C0:0x40`.

> What is the value of CS register by default when BIOS loads bootloader?

There are a few BIOSes that jump to `0x7C0:0`, but the standard seems to be `0:0x7C00`.

For this reason, many boot loaders perform a jump to `0x7C0:0x60` (as an example) to ensure that the `CS` register has a defined value.