# BIOS int 13h/AH=42 not reading disk or reading into right place in memory

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, nasm, bios

Edit:
PLEASE. FOR THE LOVE OF GOD. REMEMBER TO ADD `[BITS 16]` IF YOU ARE EXECUTING IN REAL MODE. IT WILL SAVE YOU.

I'm trying to get the BIOS to read in a little section from the disk and execute it. So far I have

```
; Boot sector if you didn't know. The entire purpose of this is to jump to protected mode setup (PMS)
%define BIOS_ERROR_FREQUENCY 440
%define ERR_LBA_NOT_FOUND    1
%define ERR_BIOS_WRITE       2

extern BIOS_BLOCK_SIZE
extern boot_sector_e
extern pms_s
extern pms_e
extern pms_number_of_blocks

section .boot
    ; Check if the BIOS supports LBA
    mov ah, 0x41
    mov bx, 0x55AA
    ; dl has already been set to the boot drive
    int 0x13
    ; Error handle
    mov al, ERR_LBA_NOT_FOUND
    jc boot_error

    ; If it does support LBA, we read in PMS to memory and start executing it
    mov ah, 0x42
    ; dl already set
    mov si, bios_lba_packet_s
    int 0x13
    mov al, ERR_BIOS_WRITE
    jc boot_error
    jmp pms_s
    ; Please note that this will overwrite and read extra from the disk. We don't know what this is however, we can just ignore it :)

    ; Misc
    bios_lba_packet_s:
    db bios_lba_packet_e - bios_lba_packet_s ; Size
    db 0 ; Reserved
    dw pms_number_of_blocks
    dw boot_sector_e ; Offset of transfer buffer location
    dw 0x0 ; Section
    dq 0 ; Starting block. We have the ability to hardcode this because it's at the set position of one sector off (boot sector is 0)
    bios_lba_packet_e:

    boot_error: ; Will just print out a upon error
        mov ah, 0x0E
        mov al, "a"
        int 0x10
        jmp $

section .boot-header
    dw 0xAA55 ; 55AA tells the BIOS that this is bootable (reversed because of endians)
```

and

```
section .pms
    mov ah, 0x0E
    mov al, "w"
    int 0x10
```

which is what I want to load in and will simply just print out "w" upon working

and I link that together with

```
SECTIONS {
    .boot ORG : {
        boot_sector_s = .;
        *( .boot );
    }
    . += BIOS_BLOCK_SIZE - boot_header_size - boot_size;
    .boot-header : {
        *( .boot-header );
        boot_sector_e = .;
    }
    
    .pms : {
        pms_s = .;
        *( .pms );
        pms_e = .;
    }
}
/* Constants */
BIOS_BLOCK_SIZE = 512;
ORG = 0x7C00;

boot_size = SIZEOF( .boot );
boot_header_size = SIZEOF( .boot-header ); /* This has be defined after the .boot-header section has been defined (it's weird, I know) */
pms_number_of_blocks = ((pms_e - pms_s) + BIOS_BLOCK_SIZE) / BIOS_BLOCK_SIZE;
```

I've dumped out the memory and the loaded in section has not been found. I also checked the carry flags and they were not set. Could it have something to do with my final binary not having padding in order to make the section I want to load in be a full 512 bytes?

Comment: Are you sure DS is what you think it is?  [Rumor has it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43359327/default-registers-and-segments-value-on-booting-x86-machine#comment73781273_43359327) that you shouldn't make assumptions about what's in the registers at bootloader time (other than DL).

Comment: dl is 0x80 which is the default HDA & ds is 0x0.

Comment: `dq 0` means you will load the first sector.

Comment: yeah i tried it with ```dq 0``` and ```dq 1``` and to no avail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the InstallationCheck function 41h reported `CF=0` does not mean everything.
You still need to verify that `BX=AA55h` to see if the IBM/MS INT 13 Extensions are indeed **installed**.
And check the *SubsetSupportBitmap* in `CX`. If bit 0 of `CX` is set then the ExtendedRead function 42h is **supported**.

> ```
> pms_number_of_blocks = ((pms_e - pms_s) + BIOS_BLOCK_SIZE) / BIOS_BLOCK_SIZE;
> ```

This will set your *pms_number_of_blocks* to just 1. You need to set the *StartingAbsoluteBlockNumber* to 1 instead of 0. (0 would be re-reading the boot sector.)

```
bios_lba_packet_s:
db 16
db 0
dw pms_number_of_blocks
dd 0:pms_s
dq 1
```

> Could it have something to do with my final binary not having padding in order to make the section I want to load in be a full 512 bytes?

Go ahead and pad it! You should always do that anyway.

---

- Strange to see "ERR_BIOS_WRITE" reported on a function that reads.
- The BIOS.Teletype function 0Eh uses the `BH` DisplayPage parameter. Set it to 0.

  ```
    section .pms
        mov  bh, 0
        mov  ax, 0x0E * 256 + "w"
        int  0x10
        times (512 - 7) db 0
  ```
- BIOS only passes you the bootdrive in the `DL` register. Nothing else! Don't trust any particular setting of the segment registers. Set `DS=0` expressly.
- Always setup a stack in a safe place. Here set it up beneath the bootsector:

  ```
    xor  ax, ax
    mov  ds, ax
    mov  ss, ax
    mov  sp, 0x7C00
  ```